# Delay Javascript effect by 500 ms

Tags: javascript, delay, easing

I want to delay slideOutItem by 500 millisecond. Canno't get that working.

```
if(current === idx) {
    slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 250, 'easeOutQuint', true);
    current = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
if(current === idx) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 250, 'easeOutQuint', true); 
    } , 500);
    current = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delayed_one  ()
{
   if(current === idx) {
      slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 250, 'easeOutQuint', true);
      current = -1;
   }
}

setTimeout ( delayed_one, 500 );
```